# How to use composer globally on MacOS Ventura

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, macos-ventura

How to use Composer globally after installing on MacOS Ventura? I tried all the guides I found googling, including the one on the composer website. It says it can't find the file.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working yet? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

All the instructions I find seem to assume that composer on a mac installs to **.composer/composer.phar** while in fact after running the php commands from getcomposer.org it installs right in the home directory.

And by default, the terminal is not bash (as most google hits ) in later MacOS but rather zsh. So this is what I had to do, after installing composer as per the instructions at getcomposer.org:

1. open terminal (**command+spacebar** and type **terminal** if you
   can't find it) go to my home folder run **nano .zsh** add **alias
   "composer"="php ~/composer.phar"** to the (previously empty) file
   Save it (by pressing **control+o**) Exit nano (by pressing ctrl+x)

   close Terminal (**command+q** or the red dot) open termianl (as the
   first line above)

composer can now be run by just typing **composer**